# SharePoint file permissions. Using Graph /permissions . Permission has SharePoint groups in the GrantedToV2. determine if user is in group?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to determine SharePoint file permissions. I'm using Graph /permissions .  Permissions have SharePoint groups in the GrantedToV2.  How can I determine if a user is in one of these groups just using the MS Graph API?

I really don't want to set up a SharePoint API oauth connection to do this. Is there a way to use the Graph API to determine whether a user is in a SharePoint group (having the group name and ID from the Permission.GrantedToV2.Group)?

Failing that, is there another way I can determine whether the user has read access, write access or owner access to the file?

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user is part of a particular group use the following query:

```
GET /me/memberOf
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/memberOf
```

Permissions required for this query:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The permission response for SharePoint groups have an ID in the identity, but it's not a real group ID so can't be used in the memberOf call.